# Copy 2d array of structures c++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, struct

I'm creating "Ships" game. I generate mField which will be my template to fill enemy field with ships. To do that I want to copy mField into eField.

My mField is dynamic 2D array of structures "Field" and it's filled like this in my cpp file:

```
mField = new Field*[x+3];
    for (int i = 0; i < x+3; ++i)
        mField[i] = new Field[y+3];
```

And declared like this in my header file

```
Field **mField;
```

Now for copying I tried

```
memcpy(&eField, &mField, sizeof(&mField));
```

although now when I fill my mField with ships an I see in enemy field exact copy of mField there instead of it being clean field.
That's how I'm passing my field to function that changes my field:

```
void Map::changeField(int x, int y, string ciag,Field **field) {
    ...
}
```

Did I make some mistake in my function that it changes both arrays or I'm copying arrays in a wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

You are copying in the enemy field pointers to your own field, this is not going to work, you are sharing the fields.

Use a `std::vector<Filed>((x+3)*(y+3))`, so a !D array of field, and access it as 2D.

If you need to use 2D arrays, allocate again new Fields for each row as you did before (hint: create a function that creates your mField and eField in a generic way).

Comment: eField and mField should be such a vector. Then pass the vector when interacting with one of the two fields. In addition of being memory safe, this also explicitly doesn't share objects between the two fields.

Comment: Oh I see now, although my professor said that I can't use vector so thats that :/ I want to make it work using arrays.

Comment: Your professor is not very smart... Modern C++ is not about handling memory yourself. Anyway, then allocate one big array of Fields, instead of a 2D array for each of the fields. And then add an explicit delete to delete each arrays.

Comment: Isn't there a way though to do this using memcpy or copy?

Comment: No, that's your error int he first place, copying pointers from your field to the enemies. And as you are using a 1D array of Field, there is no need to copy anything.

Comment: So just use `Field *mField`.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I can agree with what you are saying about Modern C++ as there are tools and techniques to handle this for you in production code, but when it comes to courses I can understand where the professors or teachers are coming from. It is still a VALID part of the language and they are trying to teach them the basics so they can learn and know what they are, how to properly use them, their strengths and weaknesses and how to avoid potential memory leaks, invalid pointers, dangling pointers and references, etc.

Comment: Agreed, but there are better ways than this.

Comment: @Michał Does your professor require you to have to use a multidimensional array, or can you simply using a regular array? If you are able to use just a single dimensional array, you can index that with what is called a `stride` and there are formulas to traverse a 1D array as if it was a 2D array. There are 2 variants as one will treat it as row - column major and the other as column - row major. If this is the case then it is easy to call new on a single dimensional array through your double for loop.

Comment: I can use whatever array I want , just not vector, list etc.. If I used stride would I be able to acces things like field[y][x]?

Comment: @FrancisCugler teaching C-style arrays is just *bad*. They aren't proper types. If you are going to teach "low level" things, `std::allocator`, `std::aligned_storage` and/or placement-new are *much* better.

Comment: @Caleth true, but like I said C-Style arrays is still valid C++ code! Here is the documentation from Microsoft; formerly MSDN now doc.microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/using-arrays-cpp?view=vs-2017 This shows you arrays, how to initialize them, how to loop through them, how they decay to pointers. It is still a part of the language and the compilers treat it that way.

Comment: I'm not saying they are non-standard. I am saying they shouldn't be used for general purpose code, and they shouldn't be taught as a collection type ahead of `vector`, `array`, `deque`. Maybe you talk about `T[]` in the same way as `forward_list` i.e. "these exist for specialised purposes, ignore them"

Comment: @Caleth Also C-style arrays is not BAD, what is bad is if the programmer doesn't know how to use them properly! That's just bad programming by the programmer. They do have their uses! The key point is knowing when and where to use them appropriately. The same thing can be said for using raw pointers, new and delete. If all new programmers are taught to completely avoid them and at a later time they come across them in some code base, they will struggler to understand what the code is doing. The same thing can be said about Macros and GOTO statements!

Comment: @Caleth If a person learns what arrays are first and how to use them properly, what their strengths and weakness are then they will understand the internal mechanics of `vector`, `list`, `set`, `map` etc.!

Comment: @Caleth Here is one example, I have a set of Vector classes, not as in container, but as in a mathematical vector. Vector2, Vector3, Vector4 and the internal containers of those classes are fixed array sizes. Now I have a Matrix class that is a fixed size and that is the same, but I also have a variable size Matrix class and that does use `std::vector`. It's knowing when, where and how to use them!

Comment: @FrancisCugler and you can probably save a bunch of code (or fix a bunch of edge-case bugs) by using `array` over `[]` in those cases

Comment: @Caleth all of those edge case bugs you are referring to are covered. The code is old yes but it belongs to 3D Graphics/Game Engine using Legacy OpenGL code, and I have a working 3D First Person Shooter that runs without bugs, memory leaks etc. and that code is riddled with arrays, raw pointers, new and delete, old school printf functions and the sort. That project was written in C++ but it was using the standard library but was limited in the use of STL. That was written between 2005 - 2010. My newer engine the uses OpenGL 3.3+ uses the STL.

Comment: @Caleth ...continued: A lot of the functions and classes contained raw pointers, some contained arrays, etc, however when it came to the Scene Graph Hierarchy I was using vectors, lists, maps etc. to contain all of the game's elements. But the mechanic parts for doing the vector & matrix math, lighting, keyboard presses etc. was using the former.

Comment: @Francis I meant using array/vector is less code than using [] correctly. And it's *harder to do incorrectly*

Comment: @Caleth Ah okay, that makes a bit more sense!

Comment: I think we all agree, with just lightly different approaches to proper teaching, but the basis are all the same ;)

Comment: @Caleth But I still feel that it is important that newbies learn it so that when they come across it in already written code, they will recognize it and know what it is, how to fix it correctly and then be able to refactor it by replacing it with the appropriate containers and algorithms. If they are ignorant of it and are assigned a task to work on existing code and try to fix what they don't understand, they can actually cause more damage and harm, cost more hours of labor and even cost more money in the long run.

Comment: I supposed this comes from the concept of a Computer Scientist - Engineer perspective over a basic programmers or coders perspective. I don't have any degrees as I'm self taught, but I strive more towards the Engineer part.

Answer (score 0):

`memcpy` simply copied **pointers** to your underlying arrays. It didn't copy ***the content*** pointed to by pointers.

Your copy function has to allocate new memory and copy the contents (aka. deep copy):

```
eField = new Field*[x+3];
for (int i = 0; i < x+3; ++i)
{
    eField[i] = new Field[y+3];
    memcpy(efield[i], mField[i], y+3);
}
```

Comment: Ugh, for some reason it still doesn't work. I even added third array hField and when i draw it it's exact copy of mField.

Comment: That's because `memcpy(efield[i], mField[i], y+3);` is wrong, this doesn't copy the content of mField to eFild, but only the first `y+3` bytes.